# higher-order function return store

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I wish to transform and store ~450k xml fragments in exist-db (v2.2). Every 15k or so records the transformation outputs a non valid (but well formed) result. In this MWE the second person's birthday is not a valid date 1225 had no February 29. Since trying to find and fix these errors is very time consuming I wish to validate the output of each transform function when storing it into the database, so I don't have to run full validation every time i m looking for outliers. I realise the difference between valid fragments vs a valid final project, but this is just to save me from coffee overdose.

I have come up with two solutions which both achieve the desired output:
based on the sample input I expect three tei:xml fragments to be validated and stored in the db, for the invalid second record an additional report should be stored in the db as well. Both scenarios generate the output, but I would like to understand the difference in behaviour of the two.

#### Scenario 1

I use `local:validate-fragments` with `local:biog` as its object, inside the final return clause as part of `xmldb:store`.

```
xquery version "3.0";

import module namespace xmldb="http://exist-db.org/xquery/xmldb";

 declare namespace tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0";
 declare namespace no="http://none";

 declare default element namespace "http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0";

 declare function local:biog ($persons as node()*) as item()* {

 for $person in $persons
 return 
     element person {
         attribute ana {'historical'}, 
         attribute xml:id {concat('BIO', $person/text())},
         element persName { $person/../no:c_name/text()},
         element birth {
             attribute when {concat($person/../no:c_birthyear, '-', $person/../no:c_by_month, '-', $person/../no:c_by_day)}
            }
        }
};

 declare function local:validate-fragment($frag as node()*, $loc as xs:string?) as item()* {

 let $id := data($frag/@xml:id)

 let $mini := 
 <TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
  <teiHeader>
      <fileDesc>
         <titleStmt>
            <title>TEI-mini</title>
         </titleStmt>
         <publicationStmt>
            <p>testing ouput of individual functions using this mini tei document </p>
         </publicationStmt>
         <sourceDesc>
            <p>cannot replace proper validation of final output</p>
         </sourceDesc>
      </fileDesc>      
  </teiHeader>
  <text>
      <body>       
         {
         switch ($loc)
         case 'person' return <listPerson ana="chunk"><listPerson ana="block">{$frag}</listPerson></listPerson>
         case 'org' return <listOrg>{$frag}</listOrg>
         case 'place' return <listPlace>{$frag}</listPlace>
         case 'bibl' return <listBibl>{$frag}</listBibl>
         default return (<p>some text here {data($frag)}</p>)
         }         
      </body>
  </text>
 </TEI>

 return 
    if (validation:jing($mini, doc('../templates/tei/tei_all.rng')) = true())
    then ($frag)
    else (($frag, 
      xmldb:store('../reports/',  concat('report-',$id,'.xml'),
      validation:jing-report($mini, doc('../templates/tei/tei_all.rng')))))
};

let $data :=
<root xmlns="http://none">
    <row>
        <c_personid>12907</c_personid>
        <c_name>Huang Zhong</c_name>        
        <c_birthyear>1226</c_birthyear>        
        <c_by_month>08</c_by_month>
        <c_by_day>26</c_by_day>        
    </row>
    <row>
        <c_personid>12908</c_personid>
        <c_name>Fang Yifu</c_name>        
        <c_birthyear>1225</c_birthyear>        
        <c_by_month>02</c_by_month>
        <c_by_day>29</c_by_day>        
    </row>
    <row>
        <c_personid>12909</c_personid>
        <c_name>Fang Linsun</c_name>        
        <c_birthyear>1215</c_birthyear>        
        <c_by_month>11</c_by_month>
        <c_by_day>06</c_by_day>
    </row>    
 </root>

 for $n in $data//no:c_personid[. > 12906][. < 12910]
 return
 xmldb:store('../samples/', concat('cbdb-', data($n), '.xml'),
 local:validate-fragment(local:biog($n), 'person')[1])
```

This is the faster of the two approaches (tested on 500 records). In the exist log this seems to perform one single write operation.

#### log

```
2017-01-31 13:08:55,263 [eXistThread-40] INFO  (RpcConnection.java [doQuery]:335) - query took 350ms. 
2017-01-31 13:08:55,263 [eXistThread-40] DEBUG (RpcConnection.java [queryP]:2854) - found 3 
2017-01-31 13:08:55,548 [eXistThread-39] DEBUG (RpcConnection.java [releaseQueryResult]:3053) - removed query result with handle 1
```

So my questions is why is the version above constantly writing and deleting in the same document in the db? Is there a better way of getting to `$frag` instead of using the tacky `[1]`? Without this predicate the whole write operation stops with an error when it reaches a `<row>` where it would need to write both a tei.xml data file and an error report. On the up side, Scenario 1 writes (and deletes) immediately to the system. Unlike…

#### Scenario 2

Call the validation function from inside the transform like this:

```
declare function local:biog ($persons as node()*) as item()* {

 for $person in $persons
 return 
    local:validate-fragment(element person {
        attribute ana {'historical'}, 
         attribute xml:id {concat('BIO', $person/text())},
        element persName { $person/../no:c_name/text()},
        element birth {
            attribute when {concat($person/../no:c_birthyear, '-', $person/../no:c_by_month, '-', $person/../no:c_by_day)}
            }
        }, 'person')

};
```

… and adopting the final clause like this:

```
for $n in $data//no:c_personid[. > 12906][. < 12910]
 return
 xmldb:store('../samples/', concat('cbdb-', data($n), '.xml'),
 local:biog($n)[1])
```

this does pollute the log with multiple write and delete statements, but does not seem to postpone the write operation until all fragments are processed.

#### log

```
2017-01-31 12:59:26,473 [eXistThread-39] INFO  (NativeBroker.java [removeXMLResource]:2641) - Removing document cbdb-12907.xml (752715) ... 
2017-01-31 12:59:26,808 [eXistThread-39] INFO  (NativeBroker.java [removeXMLResource]:2641) - Removing document report-BIO12908.xml (752714) ... 
2017-01-31 12:59:26,814 [eXistThread-39] INFO  (NativeBroker.java [removeXMLResource]:2641) - Removing document cbdb-12908.xml (752720) ... 
2017-01-31 12:59:27,048 [eXistThread-39] INFO  (NativeBroker.java [removeXMLResource]:2641) - Removing document report-BIO12909.xml (752743) ... 
2017-01-31 12:59:27,053 [eXistThread-39] INFO  (NativeBroker.java [removeXMLResource]:2641) - Removing document cbdb-12909.xml (752721) ... 
2017-01-31 12:59:27,056 [eXistThread-39] INFO  (RpcConnection.java [doQuery]:335) - query took 755ms. 
2017-01-31 12:59:27,056 [eXistThread-39] DEBUG (RpcConnection.java [queryP]:2854) - found 3
```

This ok for small chunks, but I m afraid this will become a problem when applied to the whole dataset.

Most importantly i don't understand how the xmldb:store is processed in the two scenarios.

Is there a smarter way of using xQueries higher oder function capabilities or for achieving the result I want?

Comment: Have you tried using the query profiling tool in monex (or the old admin app) to see which segments of the query are taking up the most time? Also, you mentioned you're seeing evidence in the log of the same document being stored and deleted. Can you paste in that log entry? Similarly, you mention a difference in processing time - but what timings are you seeing? Anything you can do to clarify what bottleneck you see would help - there are a lot of details in your report. I don't see the picture clearly enough at the moment to understand why you're looking to higher order functions.

Comment: @joewiz thank you for the quick response. My apologies for posting here in haste. I've updated the description to be more clear. According to the query profiler, ``xmldb:store`` receives 10 calls and takes up 4.2ms. ``local:biog`` and ``local:vaildate-frag`` each receive 8 calls taking 2.5ms. ``validate:jing`` receives 10 calls also at 2.5ms. When running on larger sets i can see that in one scenario the collection is populated with records while it is running, in the other it isn't. But thats hard to show with just 3 records.